# UIPicker didSelectRow Strange Behavior

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

I have a 3 component dependent picker and I had it working fine until I noticed a strange behavior.  If I spin component 1 and then click down with mounse on Conmponent 2, then wait for Component 1 to stop spinning then let the mouse button up, all without moving the mouse or picker wheel at all... didSelectRow does not get called at all!!!  Has anyone else seen this behavior and found a work around???

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Users will use fingers and not mouse :)
You should prefer testing these kinda things on device..

Have you already seen What happens on the device?

Comment: I checked on device - seems there's the same behaviour

Answer (score 0):

It looks like

```
pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:
```

only gets called once regardless of how many components there are. Seems missleading to me but if you're spinning more than one component, you'll have to cycle through them, calling

```
pickerView selectedRowInComponent:
```

for each, regardless of which component gets passed to the method.